# Handling Json parse exception

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to send erroneous Json request to my request body mapped to model in the controller.
I was wondering is there any way to handle the error if we rely on auto conversion of spring.

Here is my Json request and My model class structure is:

```json
{
   "name": "abcd",                             
   "occupation": "student"
   "extrafield":"hjhsda"
}
```

```java
public class User{ string name;string occupation:}
```

and my method to handle request is

```java
@PostMapping(value="/test")
public void process2(@RequestBody User user) {
   System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

I know one way to handle it is accepting json as string and using parser in method using try and catch.

Comment: Errorneous json request means, json format is not correct or you mean some required fields missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the `JsonProcessingException` in a `ControllerAdvice` class:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(JsonProcessingException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidJson(JsonProcessingException ex) {
        // handle exception
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid JSON", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

More [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).